# How to get document containing specific field?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want get only document in collection if contain specific field.

For example I try this but it not work:

```
const exampleCollection = admin.firestore().collection(‘Collection’).doc(‘Doc).collection(‘Subcollection’);

const exampleDoc = await exampleCollection.where(“field”, “>”, “”).get();
const field = await exampleDoc.data().field;
```

How to do?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you do `.where("field", ">=", " ")`, so with `>=` and a space? The reason for doing this is that space is the first printable ASCII character, so I'd expect any document that has a value for `field` to match this criteria.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for reply! I try this but it now give error: `TypeError: exampleDoc.data is not a function`

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use `.orderBy('field')` to return only those documents with that field. Firestore will automatically drop documents without that field.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform simple and compound queries in firebase.

documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries

example: `.where('field', '>', '10');`

Comment: Thanks for reply! I know this. But why is my query not work?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Firestore does not offer any type of query that simply checks to see if a property exists.  You have to check if it contains a specific value (==), or a range (greater than, less than), or its array contains some value.  In all cases, you need a specific value to compare to.  There is also no type of query that looks for data that's not present, as that type of query does not scale in the way the Firestore requires.

This probably means you will need to change your document model to suit the results you need to get.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I not know in advance which document contain this field. So only solution is get all document in collection and loop through?

Comment: Yes, that is your only option if you're not able to change the contents of the document to meet the needs of your query.

Comment: Thanks! So cannot query `where(“field”, “>”, “”)` if `field` may not be present? My theory was this will return empty string so I will know if document contain field

Comment: That won't work the way you expect. All it's doing is asking for all the documents where the string value of field sorts greater than an empty string. It will not convert non-string type field values into strings.